# How can I change the Eye of Gnome (image viewer) default initial window size?

Tags: 18.04, eog

I use my laptop monitor (resolution 1366 x 768) as a secondary display. When I open an image in this display, the image viewer window only shows part of the image and the top bar of the window is cut off. At this point (i.e., the dozens of times each day I open an image in this display) I hit <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to maximize the window and show the full image.

Is there a way to change the default initial window size of Eye of Gnome so that its height is 768 pixels?

[image: file in image_folder in Nautilus]

[image: file open and cut off the screen]